# perl stat() does not work with filenames with special characters

Tags: perl, stat

With filenames having characters like '@' perl's stat() does not seem to work.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  1 17:33 /tmp/mark@er.txt
```

Perl command used:

```
#perl -e 'my $modtime = (stat("/tmp/mark@er.txt"))[9]|| die "$!"'
  No such file or directory at -e line 1.
```

Can anyone help how to escape these characters for stat()?

Comment: try escaping `@` as `\@`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perl` "sees" a `@er` array there, so you are `stat`ing `/tmp/mark.txt`. Try this:

```
perl -e 'my $modtime = (stat("/tmp/mark\@er.txt"))[9] || die "$!"'
```

Or you can use non-interpolating single quotes by using `q()` (thanks amon)

```
perl -e 'my $modtime = (stat(q(/tmp/mark@er.txt)))[9] || die "$!"'
```

Comment: One could also use `q{}` single quotes to suppress interpolation, instead of introducing wildcards (urgh)